# Force <textarea> to take up all available space

Tags: html, css

I need to have a `<textarea>` take up all available space inside of a `<td>`

When a user clicks inside of the table cell, the `<textarea>` should appear with the **exact** dimensions of the cell (like an Excel spreadsheet).

I have tried setting the `<textarea>` width and height to 100%, but that doesn't work; the dimensions just get skewed and all the table cells jump a little bit as this cell get resized incorrectly both vertically and horizontally.

Is there a way to do this?

**edit:**

You can see how this fails here: http://jsfiddle.net/4QbMr/6/

(both cells should be the same size)

Comment: Quite honestly I would try to use something like javascript to achieve this.

Comment: I'm using jQuery to replace the text in the cell with the `<textarea>`. I just can't figure out how to get it sized to fit the cell's exact dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know whether I understand your question but you have to explicitly configure talbe cells width. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4QbMr/8/. Now it will take all the space vertically, in order to avoid this you have to wrap table in a div.

Here's code of the css:

```
    textarea
{
     width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
table tr td{
    width:100px;
}
```

html

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut lacinia mauris. Morbi condimentum feugiat diam at scelerisque. Nam lobortis placerat semper. Cras odio nisi, commodo ut viverra nec, tempus vitae elit. Suspendisse sodales, mauris at fermentum consectetur, quam odio dapibus nibh, nec porta diam tortor non ipsum. Donec vestibulum justo sit amet ipsum facilisis et accumsan orci convallis. Sed id tempus sem. Donec congue sapien ut nunc pretium sed fringilla orci interdum. Fusce viverra viverra scelerisque. Donec cursus ve
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut lacinia mauris. Morbi condimentum feugiat diam at scelerisque. Nam lobortis placerat semper. Cras odio nisi, commodo ut viverra nec, tempus vitae elit. Suspendisse sodales, mauris at fermentum consectetur, quam odio dapibus nibh, nec porta diam tortor non ipsum. Donec vestibulum justo sit amet ipsum facilisis et accumsan orci convallis. Sed id tempus sem. Donec congue sapien ut nunc pretium sed fringilla orci interdum. Fusce viverra viverra scelerisque. Donec cursus ve</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It does seem to work if you explicitly set the `<td>` width and just let the height auto-size to fit the content, looks like I'll just have to do that.

Comment: Please see answer of user @kei It looks like his approach is better

Comment: Height doesn't auto-size in IE/FF5 :D

Answer (score 5):

First, give the table cells `position:relative`

Next define `textarea` in the CSS as

```
textarea {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

***jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xXXBP/***

---

**EDIT**

***new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xXXBP/8/***

Plays nice with FF and IE now. :D

Comment: hmmm.. true. Fails for IE as well. Back to the drawing board :D

Comment: This does seem a bit hacky. I think simply specifying `<td>` widths is a much more stable/practical approach. Sorry!

Comment: No prob. I didn't take into account browser compatibility when I came up with the solution.

Comment: K.. fixed issues concerning IE and FF

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td.makeTA').click(function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    var w = $td.width();
    var h = $td.height();
    $td.append($('<textarea />').css('width',w+'px').css('height',h+'px'));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this too, and it fails just like setting width and height to 100%

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set the `table`, `tr` and `td` `height` to your size, and then the `td` size to "***100/#ofrow***"% (or a fixed width).

like in [your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QbMr/9/)

```
textarea
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;  
}

td {width:50%;/*for 2 columns*/}
table, tr, td{height:100%}
```