# How to get a textarea to fill in the height of a table column?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKB9e/3/) click on the "Add Question" button in the demo so it will append a table row. The problem I have is that if you look under the "Question" column in the appended row, the `textarea` does not fill the height of its column. How can I get each textarea in its appended row to fill the height of its table column?

Below is part of the CSS code for this:

```
.question { 
    min-width:14%;
    max-width:14%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question textarea {
    min-width:auto;
    max-width:auto;
    resize:none;
    height:auto;
    font-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: Set it's height to `100%`. That means 100% of the parents height.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946228/force-textarea-to-take-up-all-available-space  I simply copied your title and pasted it into Google and it was the second result...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah I tried height:100% before but the problem which I don't get that even though the code in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LKB9e/5/ and the code in my application [app](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php) are exactly the same, it works in the fiddle but not in application. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @user1830984. No idea, and I don't really have time to diff your code. Could be something else in your CSS which is interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `<textarea>` has displayed as inline block and vertically-aligned to the baseline.
Change any of two:

```
.question textarea {
  display: block;

  /* or */

  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

That space on the bottom is the part of line-height reserved for letters that extend below the baseline, like 'g' or 'y'. So nullifying parent's line-height will also work *(not sure about Safari):*

```
.question {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1830984 You didn't apply anything cause there is no parent with class `question`; selector should be `#question textarea`.

Comment: There is a parent class selector, it is in the javascript code where it appends the textarea

Comment: Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKB9e/9/, please try get it working in fiddle and then I will mark answer if hopefully it works in my app as well